# sql best strategy to partition same values based on temporal sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data that looks like this, where there are multiple values for each ID that correspond to an ascending date variable:

```
ID  LEVEL  DATE
1   10     10/1/2000
1   10     11/20/2001
1   10     12/01/2001
1   30     02/15/2002
1   30     02/15/2002
1   20     05/17/2002
1   20     01/04/2003
1   30     07/20/2003
1   30     03/16/2004
1   30     04/15/2004
```

I want to acquire a count per each ID/LEVEL/DATE block that looks like this:

```
ID   LEVEL  COUNT
1    10        3
1    30        2
1    20        2
1    30        3
```

The problem is that if I use the count windows function and partition by level, it groups 30 together regardless of the temporal sequence. I want the count for level 30 both before and after 20 to be distinct. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Which dialect of SQL?  There are several solutions, but they vary from SQL Server to MySQL to Oracle, etc, etc.  Also, for your own information, this is often referred to as `gaps and islands`.

Comment: Oracle-oh ok, yea, I'm not familiar with that concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard `gaps and islands` solution using `ROW_NUMBER()`, if it's available on your particular DBMS...

```
WITH
  ordered AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id        ORDER BY date)   AS set_ordinal,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, level ORDER BY date)   AS grp_ordinal
  FROM
    yourData
)
SELECT
  id,
  level,
  set_ordinal - grp_ordinal,
  MIN(date),
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  ordered
GROUP BY
  id,
  level,
  set_ordinal - grp_ordinal
ORDER BY
  id,
  MIN(date)
```

Visualising the effect of the two row numbers...

```
ID  LEVEL  DATE        set_ordinal  grp_ordinal  set-grp    GROUP
--  -----  ----------  -----------  -----------  -------    --------
 1     10  10/01/2000            1     1               0    1,10,0
 1     10  11/20/2001            2     2               0    1,10,0
 1     10  12/01/2001            3     3               0    1,10,0

 1     30  02/15/2002            4         1           3    1,30,3
 1     30  02/15/2002            5         2           3    1,30,3

 1     20  05/17/2002            6       1             5    1,20,5
 1     20  01/04/2003            7       2             5    1,20,5

 1     30  07/20/2003            8         3           5    1,30,5
 1     30  03/16/2004            9         4           5    1,30,5
 1     30  04/15/2004           10         5           5    1,30,5
```

Comment: Great, I will try that!

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: I have a follow up question. Is there any way to keep the grouped-by levels in the same temporal sequence? Using the above data, for example, some of my levels are being grouped as 10, 20, 30, 30, rather than 10, 30, 20, 30. I'm not sure how to maintain the order of the dates when also using the group by function.

Comment: @epstewar - I recommend creating an actual new question, rather than just a comment.  In that include the code you are using, in case of typos or mistakes, and some example data that demonstrates your issues.  Then I'll certainly have a look.  *(I've added what **might** be what you need to the answer above)*

Comment: Ok, I was just about to post the question, but then I saw your edit. That works! Thanks so much.